# Cannot run ASP.NET site in standalone installation of IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have installed IIS Express on a machine with Windows 8.1. I tried to activate the ASP.NET features but all request to my ASP.NET site still gives an internal server error. It can serve static pages so the server starts ok. It is the ASP.NET pages that does not run. Any ideas about a specific install order or settings that has to be done after install?

Comment: is asp.net installed. if not refer this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: That command does not run on Win 8.1 unfortunately. It outputs that it should be enabled in Windows features, which I have done I believe.

Comment: %windir%\system32\DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET45 /All /quiet /NoRestart

Comment: can you check if this runs

Comment: It seems as the problem might be that we only have 2Gb Ram. At least we do get a OutOfMemory exception. Now changed to another hardware and it works.

Comment: You should at least be aware that IIS and IIS Express are different things. When you hit an internal server error, you should also paste the detailed error message here so others can see what's up.